# node express/request: piping a POST request with body parsing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-request

I'm attempting to pipe a request for handling by a remote server, along the following lines:

```
var destination = request(url);
req.pipe(destination).pipe(res);
```

This works just fine for `GET` requests.  But for `POST` requests I'm struggling.  An important point to note, I think, is that for `POST` requests I'm using a body parser before my `POST` route handler in order to extract the body from the `POST` request... it's just a basic text body parser because the body contains plain text:

```
var postRouteHandler = someFunction;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var textParser = bodyParser.text({
    limit: '50kb'
});
app.use('/postRoute', [textParser, postRouteHandler]);
```

From [this issue](https://github.com/request/request/issues/1664) and [this issue](https://github.com/request/request/issues/1616) it seems to me that doing any processing on the `POST` request before you pipe it will cause a problem.  Indeed, when I remove the parser, the piping seems to work OK.

The problem is that I need to examine the body first, to do some initial processing and then to determine whether or not to pipe the request on to the remote server at all.  So I *need* to parse the body before piping.

Is there any way around this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue is that with streams (like `req`), once you've read it you can't reset it.

Because `body-parser` has read the stream already, piping it won't work because that will try to read the stream again (which at that point has been exhausted).

A workaround would be take the text read by `body-parser`, and create a minimal `req` "clone" in order for `request` to be able to pass the request along:

```
var intoStream = require('into-stream');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var textParser = bodyParser.text({ limit: '50kb' });

var postRouteHandler = function(req, res) {
  let text = req.body;
  if (! shouldPipe(text)) {
    return res.sendStatus(400); // or whatever
  }

  // Here's where the magic happens: create a new stream from `text`,
  // and copy the properties from `req` that `request` needs to pass
  // along the request to the destination.
  let stream     = intoStream(text);
  stream.method  = req.method;
  stream.headers = req.headers;

  // Pipe the newly created stream to request.
  stream.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);
};
app.use('/postRoute', [textParser, postRouteHandler]);
```

Comment: Learn from the master!  Genius!  Not only a great solution, but also a clear and succinct explanation of why the problem happens.  You are indeed the master @robertklep!

Comment: ... just one thing... should it be `request.post(url)` rather than just `request(url)`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `request` will use `req.method/stream.method` to determine what type of request to perform, so you don't have to be explicit about it.

Comment: I cant seem to be able to use into-stream (node with version 6.14, can I use another 3rd party instead? is there another option?)

Comment: @OmriShneor into stream is a package on npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/into-stream

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own middleware if the parser is causing the problem.  In all honesty you may want to parse the body a different way than the body parser.

Given the limited knowledge about what the rest of your project is doing you could create middleware to hook the body parser middleware and just send a clone of request. This however is not very efficient but will work and may help point you in the right direction.

```
var postRouteHandler = someFunction;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var textParseMiddleware = function (req, res, next) {

  var requestclone = _.clone(req);
  var textParser = bodyParser.text({
    limit: '50kb'
  });

  textParser(requestclone, res, function(){
    console.log('examine the body here', requestclone.body);
  });


}

app.use('/postRoute', [textParserMiddleWare, postRouteHandler]);
```

I have not tested the above code.

Answer (score -1):

Need to send a huge large data via POST, I was getting  Error: socket hang up /  code: 'ECONNRESET'.
Was able to resolve it via increasing limit in body parser.

`var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:'50mb'}));`

Comment: How does this answer the question? Kindly ensure you answer relates to the question asked.