# req.pipe - TypeError: reqPipe is not a function

Tags: javascript, express, busboy

I'm trying to upload some files with AWS using the `busboy` module, but when I use `req.pipe` to say that `busboy` is controlling the response, I get the error:

> `req.pipe` is not a function.

Here is my code:

```
const uploadDeArquivos = async (reqHeaders, reqFiles, reqBody, reqPipe) => {
    let bb = busboy({ headers: reqHeaders });

    bb.on('finish', async () => {
        const { salaoId, servico } = reqBody;
        let errors = [];
        let arquivos = [];

        if(reqFiles && Object.keys(reqFiles).length > 0) {
            for (let key of Object.keys(reqFiles)) {
                const file = reqFiles[key];
                const splitName = file.name.split('.');
                const fileName = `${new Date().getTime()}.${
                    splitName[splitName.length - 1]
                }`;
                const path = `servicos/${salaoId}/${fileName}`;

                const response = await aws.uploadToS3(file, path);

                response.error 
                    ? errors.push({ error: true, message: response.message })
                    : arquivos.push(path);
            };
        };

        if (errors.length > 0) throw errorThrow(500, errors[0]);

        // Criar Serviço
        let jsonServico = JSON.parse(servico);
        const novoServico = await Servico(jsonServico).save();

        // Criar arquivo
        arquivos = arquivos.map(arquivo => ({
            referenciaId: novoServico._id,
            model: 'Servico',
            caminho: arquivo,
        }));

        await Arquivo.insertMany(arquivos);

        return { 
            servico: novoServico, 
            arquivos 
        };
    });

    reqPipe(bb);
};

const newServico = async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        const newServico = await uploadDeArquivos(req.headers, req.files, req.body, req.pipe);
        return res.status(201).json(newServico);
    } catch(error){
        next(error);
    }
};

router.post('/', newServico);
```

Comment: Where is that function being called? And if you `console.log(typeof reqPipe)` at the top of the function, what is it?

Comment: I'll post the rest of the code.

Comment: @ZacAnger the console.log tell me it's a function.

Comment: First issue, don't shadow variables (in your controller, you're using the same variable name for the service as for the value returned from your service). Secondly, your error says `req.pipe` is not a function but you're calling it `reqPipe` in the service, so it seems like the error is coming from somewhere else (maybe busboy internals?). Do you have any middlewares that could be interfering with the req object, and are you using `req.pipe` anywhere else in your code?

Comment: I'm using express.json(), bodyParser, morgan, busboy and cors as middlewares. And I'm just using **req.pipe** in that file.

Comment: Once the request stream is exchausted, `req.pipe` won't be available. express-busboy and bodyParser both would conflict with using req.pipe later on in the code path because they read from the request to parse the POSTed body. There's a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44574905/5774952), which you could adapt to your use-case, or you could configure those two middlewares to skip this specific `content-type`.

Comment: @ZacAnger I modified my bodyParser.json(), now it looks like this:
-
`app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb', type(_req) { return true }}));`
There is no conflict with busboy now, however the error appears:
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0`.
And the body starts like this:
`'--X-INSOMNIA-BOUNDARY\r\n'`

Comment: That error is expected because you told bodyParser.json to accept any content-type, including things that aren't JSON, so of course it would fail trying to parse non-JSON requests. Likely this "fixed" things a bit because that means the busboy middleware isn't trying to handle your multipart request. I recommend maybe commenting out both of those middlewares, seeing if your upload service works, and then enabling specific features in the middlewares one by one, just ones you actually need for your application.

Comment: I don't know what else to do, because when I remove the bodyParser and try to upload it, the following error appears: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_readableState')`, and I left the generic type, because it it is not accepting the other types.